# I am implementing Expires headers, but they don't seem to be working

Tags: .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on

# Your document html
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"

# Media: images, video, audio
ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"

# CSS and JavaScript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

I have this code in my htaccess file, but for some reason when I run tests on my site at gtmetrix, it tells me there are no expires headers

Do I have the code wrong, or am I not including something else? Does there need to be something on each page to make this work?